# how to create Windows shortcuts with izPack 5.0b11?

Tags: izpack

I have to create a shortcut at the end of the installation process.
This is what i declared in my install.xml

```
<resources>
  ...
  <res id="shortcutSpec.xml" src="install/shortcuts.xml"/>
</resources>

<panels>
  <panel classname="ShortcutPanel">
    <os family="windows"/>
  </panel>
</panels>

<natives>
    ...
   <native type="izpack" name="ShellLink.dll" stage="both">
     <os family="windows" />
   </native>
   <native type="izpack" name="ShellLink_x64.dll" stage="both">
     <os family="windows" />
    </native>
</natives>
```

And this is the content of my shortcuts.xml:

```
<shortcuts>
    <skipIfNotSupported />
    <programGroup defaultName="MyGroup" location="applications" />
    <shortcut name="MyApplication" target="$INSTALL_PATH\bin\open.bat"
    workingDirectory="$INSTALL_PATH" iconFile="$INSTALL_PATH\bin\App32.ico"
    iconIndex="0" programGroup="no" desktop="yes" applications="yes"
    startMenu="yes" startup="false">
        <os family="windows" />
    </shortcut>
</shortcuts>
```

When i run the setup i am able to see the shortcuts panel, but the shortcut is never created in the desktop nor in other known locations.

Is there something i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

I notes that in the showrtcuts panel there is a checkbox 'create shortcut in the desktop'.
If you select this option the shortcut is correctly created in the desktop.